# Convert SUMPRODUCT into VBA on large data set

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, sumifs, sumproduct

I currently have a large dataset which i produce a summary on using multiple criteria.  Currently i use Sumproduct which works but the data is large and so using lots of Sumproduct causes the spreadsheet to be slow.

In VBA i tried a couple of things, Evaluate the Sumproduct in a loop and paste answer as value, and also tried WorksheetFunction SUMIFS as well but also very slow.

I have seen examples in VBA of data dictionary which looks good but not sure i can replicate it.

Example of my data:

```
StartDate    StartTime  EndDate     EndTime   ID      Quantity
07/10/2019   00:30:00   07/10/2019  01:30:00  ABC123   1000
07/10/2019   00:01:00   08/10/2019  17:30:00  ABC123   15
07/10/2019   03:30:00   09/10/2019  12:00:00  123ABC   2000
07/10/2019   00:01:00   10/10/2019  11:00:00  ABC123   55
```

Summary Sheet:
ID, Date and Time criteria are already populated.  The VBA would output the amount based on the criteria in the Quantity Column.

```
ID ABC123

Date         Time      Quantity
07/10/2019   00:00:00  
07/10/2019   00:30:00
07/10/2019   01:00:00
07/10/2019   01:30:00
```

Criteria:
Sum Quantity for ID ABC123 if StartDate <= Date, StartTime <= Time, End Date >= Date, EndTime > Time

Example Excel Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((StartDate<=$I3)*(StartTime<=$J3)*(EndDate>=$I3)*(EndTime>$J3)*(ID=$J$1)*Quantity)
```

Result:

```
ID ABC123

Date         Time      Quantity
07/10/2019   00:00:00   0
07/10/2019   00:30:00   1070
07/10/2019   01:00:00   1070
07/10/2019   01:30:00   70
```

To emphasis i have tried SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT in VBA but the summary output is a massive time series sheet with lots and lots of rows of data and so it really struggled.

Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: VBA will not work nearly as fast as the native excel functions. I assume Pivot Table is not realistic?

Comment: A help column in your data set might also speed it up if you can get a single sumif.

Comment: First thing I'm thinking would be to play around with `AutoFilter` and sum `xlCellTypeVisible`

Comment: Combining the time and date into a single value would reduce the number of conditions and perhaps speed things up

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I thought about that too, but the range of time makes it difficult.

Comment: What does "the range of time makes it difficult" mean? add the date and time, format as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` and you're done combining them

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad you're right. I was thinking you meant put EVERYTHING into a single cell, but as your comment said, simply reducing the number of columns/conditions would indeed speed things up.